# null detection for double method

Tags: java, methods, null, double

I'm employing a private lib. One of the objects has a method that delivers either a double or a null.

How could I perform:

```
if (object.method != null) {
    // do some numeric operations with the returned value
}
```

Additional details:

```
library = org.apache.commons.collections4.map
class = LRUmap
method = get
```

My code is:

```
public class ExampleNode extends GeneralNode {
    private LRUMap<Integer, Double> cache;

    public ExampleNode() {
        this.setCache(new LRUMap<Integer,Double>(100));
    }    

    public void setCache(LRUMap<Integer, Double> lruMap) {
        this.cache = lruMap;
    }

    public double getDatumCacheDebug(int llave){
        return this.cache.get((Object)llave,false);
    }
}
```

And then I call:

```
//outside ExampleNode
    if ( actualNode.getDatumCacheDebug(k) != null ) {
```

Eclipse Neon3 says: **"The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double,null."**

Comment: Hi, please show the type signature of the method that can return a double or null. In Java, it's not possible to declare a method that you can either return a `double` or a `null`. It is possible to declare a method that returns a `Double` - which can also return a `null`. But you wouldn't get the error that you describe for a method that is declared to return a `Double`.

Comment: it should be 0 and not null because it is a primitive type and not a reference type

Comment: ohhh
library = org.apache.commons.collections4.map
class = LRUmap
method = get

Comment: Show the code you employ to call that method. The code you posted in your question currently is broken since it doesn't invoke any method (it doesn't have parentheses after `object.method`). LRUMap is a typical generic map and the `get` method returns a reference - it does *not* return `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the [library method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) is:

```
public V get(Object key,
    boolean updateToMRU)
```

in class `LRUMap<K,V>`

The returned value is a `Double`, and therefore could be null, but it is being unboxed to `double` before the null test:

```
public double getDatumCacheDebug(int llave){
    return this.cache.get((Object)llave,false);
}
```

I suggest changing the signature of this method to return `Double` instead of `double`, so that the information about whether the result was null is preserved and can be tested. Otherwise, it will throw `NullPointerException` if `get` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

When the method returns a primitive `double` (and not the `Double` class), it can never be `null`. A primitive value will always have a value of its type (i. e. you can't do `double d = null;`).

Thus this check would never return true and the compiler does not allow you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A working variant of your code will be:

```
if (object.method != 0) {
    // do some numeric operations with the returned value
}
```

But it is better practice to refactor your method object.method() to return a specific number for your "null cases"- *example: a method that is searching for an index in a list - returns the index number if found and -1 if not found or exception is thrown during the search (a null case for the search)*